# Cloth passes through Rigid Body

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, cloth-simulation, soft-body

I would like the cloth to fall and hit the bricks, but it just passes through. I've replaced the bricks with a rigid cube before and it does the same thing. Am I missing something? I'll include the file and a GIF.

Thanks[image: Cloth Passing Through]

Comment: File is not included just a GIF that is not illustrative enough.To attach your simplified blend file to see your setup, use https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com and paste given code into your question. In meantime just to be sure ... do you have to set "Collision" to Brick Wall?

Comment: Hello Vkildu. I've been trying to upload the file for a while to no avail. I did set the collision to brick wall but that didn't work either. Hopefully I can get the file to go through soon. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Share your file any other way so I  can try to attach for you here. Just delet all that doesn't generate your issue. BTW Instead of bricks you can use any other object as whole a wall and hide it from rendering.

Comment: Here is a download link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/uijtt1smq2jh4ii/banners.blend?dl=0                      Hiding a wall during the render is a good idea! didnt think of that.

Answer (score 2):

*When I asked to simplify the blend, I ment to keep one example of cloth, only bricks that directly collide with cloth, there is no need to keep brick with a huge amount of vertices for this issue, so *Decimate* modifier could be applied (it slows down calculation any time you run simulation). You have also set *Fake User* for many objects. When deleted from a scene, they are still a part of file. To get rid of them you have to go into Outliner > Ophan Data > uncheck all of them and hit Purge. If objects are still there you can select them manually with Shift and with right-click choose Delet. Like that you can go from 184 MB to just 4 MB for a blend you could share with us (saved with compression enabled).*

---

[image]

**Collision**
If you set *Rigid Body* just for colision with cloth (and you don't plan to destroy a wall later), it would not work.
You have to enable **Collision** that you can find above *Cloth* Simulation.

[image]

Tips:

- If you plan just collide a cloth with a wall I would suggest you to use a simple plane (subdivided a few times), that is much faster for collision calculation.
- To deactivate *Rigid Body* sim for all bricks at once - go to *Scene Properties > Rigid Body World > Remove ...* (it will remove all rigid body in a scene).
- Quite annoying is cached cloth sim, that is not always updated when you change parametr. To recalculate sim with actual setup, I know only one way - deactivate&activate monitor icon on *Cloth* button.
- To apply modifier for all selected objects, search for *Convert to Mesh*. Sounds weird, right? It is a mesh already, but this operator apply all transformations at once for all selected.

Comment: I gotcha. Thanks for the info, I'm just starting out with blender. I appreciate you taking the time to check it out, it means alot.

Comment: You'r welcome :) If answer solved your issue consider mark it as accepted, so others with similar issue can see it from main list. Thank you keep site organised. https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour